# Exception: Complete output mode not supported

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I created sparkStreaming Simulation for my tutorial. When I do the outputMode ("complete") operation, I get an error.

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Complete output mode not supported when there are no streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;
```

My dataset example:

```
2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200,Partly Cloudy,rain,9.472222222222221,7.3888888888888875,0.89,14.1197,251.0,15.826300000000002,0.0,1015.13,Partly cloudy throughout the day.
```

First process code (Partition(summary)):

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C:\\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master");
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("SparkStreamingMessageListener")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
StructType schema = new StructType()
                .add("Formatted Date", "String")
                .add("Summary","String")
                .add("Precip Type", "String")
                .add("Temperature", "Double")
                .add("Apparent Temperature", "Double")
                .add("Humidity","Double")
                .add("Wind Speed (km/h)","Double")
                .add("Wind Bearing (degrees)","Double")
                .add("Visibility (km)","Double")
                .add("Loud Cover","Double")
                .add("Pressure(milibars)","Double")
                .add("Dailiy Summary","String");
Dataset<Row> formatted_date = sparkSessionDataFrame.read().schema(schema).option("header", true).csv("C:\\Users\\Kaan\\Desktop\\Kaan Proje\\SparkStreamingListener\\archivecsv\\weatherHistory.csv");
Dataset<Row> avg = formatted_date.groupBy("Summary", "Precip Type").avg("Temperature").sort(functions.desc("avg(Temperature)"));
formatted_date.write().partitionBy("Summary").csv("C:\\Users\\Kaan\\Desktop\\Kaan Proje\\SparkStreamingListener\\archivecsv\\weatherHistoryFile\\");
```

Second listener process code:

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("SparkStreamingMessageListener1")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
StructType schema1 = new StructType()
                .add("Formatted Date", "String")
                .add("Precip Type", "String")
                .add("Temperature", "Double")
                .add("Apparent Temperature", "Double")
                .add("Humidity","Double")
                .add("Wind Speed (km/h)","Double")
                .add("Wind Bearing (degrees)","Double")
                .add("Visibility (km)","Double")
                .add("Loud Cover","Double")
                .add("Pressure(milibars)","Double")
                .add("Dailiy Summary","String");
 Dataset<Row> rawData = sparkSession.readStream().schema(schema1).option("sep", ",").csv("C:\\Users\\Kaan\\Desktop\\Kaan Proje\\sparkStreamingWheather\\*");
        Dataset<Row> heatData = rawData.select("Temperature", "Precip Type").where("Temperature>10");
        StreamingQuery start = heatData.writeStream().outputMode("complete").format("console").start();
        start.awaitTermination();
```

I created a Streaming simulation by copying the partitioned files to the specified Listener file path.
I would be glad if you help.Thanks.

Comment: Hi @TheCrucial. Please note that Stackoverflow is not a discussion board but rather a focused Q&A site. If you find my answer useful, feel free to accept it (tick mark on the left hand side of the answer box). If you have a new question please open a new question and avoid using screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty specific in telling what the actual problem is: the output mode complete is not supported for the type of your query.

As stated in the Structured Streaming Guide on [OutputeModes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes):

> "Complete mode not supported as it is infeasible to keep all unaggregated data in the Result Table."

This issue will be solved when selecting the append mode:

```
StreamingQuery start = heatData.writeStream().outputMode("append").format("console").start()
```